# Equal Variance Assumption- Levene's Test with different sample size

Tags: r, statistical-significance, levenes-test

Between-subject & repeated measures experiment & with two groups: Treatment and control. I have 15 in treatment and 20 in control.

Can I use Levene's Test with an unequal sample size?

`LevenesTest(Independent ~ Dependent)` - is it just hypothesis testing?
I don't understand the test, I am looking for variance in the group but with respect to what?

Can someone make it clear?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can use variables with different sample sizes.

The null hypothesis is that variables are equal:

$$H_0: \sigma_1=\sigma_2$$

The alternative hypothesis is that they are not equal

$$H_A: \sigma_1 \neq \sigma_2$$

You can choose whether treatment or control is 1 or 2, but once you make the choice you should be consistent.

Also note that the test can be extended to arbitrarily large number of groups I used only 2 to apply it to your problem.

Comment: Thank you, so  Levene's Test is a hypothesis test? As I am expecting the treatment and the control group to have different effects?

Comment: @mashedpoteto by definition any test is hypothesis test. You can’t have test without testing some concept and name for that in statistics jargon is hypothesis. If you want to test for different treatment effect then Levine test will not suffice you can first use the Levine test to see if variances are equal and then based on that choose t-test with equal or unequal variances if you want to test some simple difference in means. If you want to test something more complex than you will need to build some model for that

Comment: here what do you mean by equal variance? I am testing a treatment group and a control group, then by just showing they have unequal variance via a Levene test, why do an addition T-Test?

Comment: @mashedpoteto I don’t know what you want to show with your research. If you just want to show that the variance is significantly different in treatment group then Levine test is enough. If you want to show that the mean in treatment is different than it’s not enough. Suppose you want to see if a new drug reduces cholesterol well it’s not enough to show that the cholesterol levels in treated patients have different variability - what you care is about if on average the cholesterol is lower. If your research is about variability that’s fine it’s not what most people do so I did not assumed that

Comment: I have a mixed model analysis pipeline, but I was checking the assumptions and for levene's test I got a p-value smaller than 0.5. And for my mixed model analysis with random effects, I did an ANOVA. Now I'm confused, should I use some non-parametric analysis tool for the ANOVA?

Comment: @mashedpoteto no that’s fine - from your original post it looked like you are just doing Levine test and nothing else

Comment: But then, I don't understand why have the Levene's test assumption in the first place? Because if it's positive then the T-Test will fail? Then all T-Test and Anova by default should be non-parametric to get a positive result?? @1muflon1

Comment: Sorry about the confusion, So even if the Levene's fails I can just go ahead and do a normal aov(iv~dv)?

Comment: @mashedpoteto Why? You can run t test or other kinds of tests with unequal variables - non-parametric tests are needed for case when the precise distribution is unknown not when you just have case that two distributions have unequal variance

Comment: This is very useful information!!!

Comment: @mashedpoteto you are welcome, I also forgot to add that you can run t-tests and other test with unequal variables but of course formulas change a bit and so also the command in your program you are using might be bit different so be careful don’t just use t-test version for equal variance for everything

Comment: can you give an example?

Comment: @mashedpoteto sure for equal variances the two distribution t test is t=(x1-x2)/(sigma*sqrt(1/n1+1/n2))) for unequal variances then t test is t=(x1-x2)/sqrt(sigma^2_1/n1 +sigma^2_2/n2)) where x1 and x2 are the respective means for groups sigma is the standard deviation in equal case and sigma^2_1 and sigma^2_2 are the variance in unequal case. N1 and n2 are sample sizes. You can find greater detail in some undergraduate econometrics textbook.